# Find strings in a list that between specific ascii values - Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find certain string in a list that are between a lowerbound and upperbound (these are user input values). For example say I have a list, states = ['OH', 'NJ', 'NY', 'SD', 'NH', 'WI']. The user inputs lowerbound = 'NJ' and upperbound = 'SD'. I want the code to output ['OH', 'NJ', 'NY', 'SD'].

What I thought I could do is to separate each string into its own individual characters.

So for the user inputs I wrote this so that the ascii values of the input are added. Each character is added from the input in this case.

```
a = ord(lowerbound[0].lower()) + ord(lowerbound[1].lower())
b = ord(upperbound[0].lower()) + ord(upperbound[1].lower())
```

So then I tried this to retrieve the elements in a list that are between the user input. First it coverts all the elements in the list to their added ascii value. But it is not giving me the output I desire.

```
s_lst = []
lst = []
for s in states:
    x = ord(s[0].lower()) + ord(s[1].lower())
    lst.append(x)
    for i in lst:
        if (b >= i >= a):
            s_lst.append(i)
print(s_lst)
```

Comment: Python is perfectly capable of comparing strings.

Comment: Python strings can be compared lexically - e.g., str_1 < str_2

Comment: What is the point of `lst`?

Comment: `[x for x in sorted(states) if a<=x<=b]`

Comment: @not_speshal: Are you claiming that either "NJ" < "OH" or "OH" < "SD" is false?

Comment: @ScottHunter - Nope. I was just wondering if OP had a different logic than the default i.e. checking the second letter of each even the first already decides the < >. Not sure why they are adding both letters for the comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to filter the list:

```
states = ['OH', 'NJ', 'NY', 'SD', 'NH', 'WI']

lowerbound = 'NJ'
upperbound = 'SD'

>>> [state for state in states if lowerbound<=state<=upperbound]
['OH', 'NJ', 'NY', 'SD']
```